# I have used 3 nested for loops to fetch the data from excel, only 2 inner for loops are executing. Using selenium webdriver - java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
for ( int k = 1;k < totalNoOfRows; k++) {   
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalNoOfCols; j++) {
            arrayExcelData[i - 1][j] = sh.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        }
    }
    k++;
}
```

The outer for loop is not executing

Comment: It is fetching only the first row content.

Comment: What is the value of `totalNoOfRows`? did you try debugging the program?

Comment: I don't know about all this elenium/excel business, but you're incrementing `k` twice. Is that intentional?

Comment: totalNoOfRows is 5 including headers. Ignore the K++ at the last.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from excel than no need to use 3 nested loops, you can achieve this in two loops easily.

```
 int rowCount = (sh.getLastRowNum()+1)
    Row row= sh.getRow(0);
    int columnCount = row.getLastCellNum();


    String[][] arrayExcelData= new String[rowCount][columnCount];

     for (int x = 0; x < rowCount; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < columnCount; y++) {
       arrayExcelData[x][y] = sh.getRow(x).getCell(y).getStringCellValue(); 


                    }
                }
```

Comment: The scenario is there are 4 methods and 4 rows of text. 1st method should fetch 1st row, 2nd method should fetch second row. But now, all the methods are fetching 1st row, 2nd row...... making total of 16 instead of 4.

Comment: can you share your code how you are passing values to methods

Comment: questions.addSingleChoice(q, a1, a2, a3, a4);
questions.addMultipleChoice(q, a1, a2, a3, a4);
questions.addTextAnswer(q);
questions.addRatingQuestion(q);

Comment: Are you providing these values to function using dataProvider?

Comment: yes. it is fetching the values also. questions.addSingleChoice(q, a1, a2, a3, a4) should fetch 1st row. questions.addMultipleChoice(q, a1, a2, a3, a4) should fetch second row. But both the methods are fetching the first row only.

Comment: Better create separate dataProvider for each function, and if you are fetching  only one row for each function then don't use loop, just fetch values by row can column number.

Comment: It is working when created a separate data provider for each function. Thanks.